# Listdefinition & DataExtender: Custom Icons

Tags: gui-extensions, 2011-sp1

I have my custom listdefinitions up and running quite good but have just some fine-tuning left to do. I would want to add some custom icons instead of those that are used by Tridion. 
I have defined my own column according to how Tridion does it for his icons.

```
<list:column id="IconColumn" type="icon" title="" selector="@ItemIcon" width="20" enableresizing="false" enablesorting="false" enablefiltering="false" />
```

I also added the following to the editor.config:

```
<itemicons>
  <icon match="act\." path="/Themes/Default/Icons/mmIcons/${icon}.${size}x${size}.png" />
</itemicons>
```

And the icons are available.

The question now is, what do I give as data from the Data Extender to get the icons that I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List definitions processed by `Tridion.Controls.ListDefinition`, where `Tridion.Controls.ListColumn` is created for each list column.

If the column represents an icon, `Tridion.Controls.ListColumn` resolves icon path

```
Tridion.Controls.ListColumn.prototype.getIconPath = function ListColumn$getIconPath(iconValue)
{
    return $config.getIconPath(iconValue, 16);
};
```

Where

```
$config.getIconPath = function Configuration$getIconPath(iconName, iconSize, forceLoad, editor)
{
    return $config.expandThemePath("icon{2}.png?name={0}&size={1}{3}".format(iconName, iconSize || "16", $config.getPathVersion(), forceLoad ? "&" + (new Date()).getTime() : ""), editor);
};
```

Where `icon.png` is processed by `Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Http.IconUrlRewriter`

Which eventually does processing based on configuration rules.

Based on your configuration, for instance request like:

```
<bc:Item ItemIcon="beard"/>
```

will be resolved from `/Themes/Default/Icons/mmIcons/beard.16x16.png`
(if requested from list details view)

And from `/Themes/Default/Icons/mmIcons/beard.48x48.png`
(if requested from thumbnails view)

**UPDATE**:

To use your Extension theme, you should add `${theme}` to your icon path

```
<settings>
    ...
    <itemicons>
      <icon match="act\." path="${theme}Icons/mmIcons/${icon}.${size}x${size}.png" />
    </itemicons>
    <theme>
        <path>/Themes/Default/</path>
    </theme>
    ...
</settings>
```

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth answer! But is there a nice way to include icons without putting them into the CME? 
My solution to this was overwriting the $config.getIconPath a function that checked the iconName for a special sequence and would change the editor string to the name of my own editor. But this is quite hacky so I was wondering if there was a nicer way.

Comment: See `update` section. It should help

Comment: Yeah, but it is only 1/2 of the problem. The function $config.getIconPath has a parameter editor which should be set to 'MyEditor' but ListColumn does not pass param to $config.getIconPath.