# How to add Custom Icons in DataExtender

Tags: web8, gui-extensions

I have created DataExtender column to show Publishing Target name for publishing status.
Now I want to show icon instead of Target Name.

I tried follow below link:

[Listdefinition & DataExtender: Custom Icons](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/8121/listdefinition-dataextender-custom-icons)

But I am unable to find Web 8 class which I can use to resolve icon path.

Answer (score -1):

Issue got resolved.

As SDL suggested in extension we need to change the type from data to icon and in return value just send image path `"<img src= ..."`

Thanks

Abhishek